# Nested search/filtering with Laravel/Eloquent

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

Let's say i have a table of houses, each of which has many rooms, each of which has many items in it. Each item has a color.

```
Houses
+ id
+ name

Rooms
+ id
+ house_id (FK house.id)
+ name

Items
+ id
+ room_id (FK room.id)
+ name
+ color
```

The corresponding model relationships ($this->hasMany()) has been set up.

I then want to return a nested JSON object with all the **red** items in it, with the houses as the top level of the object. That is, the JSON object is structured as a list of houses, each of which has a list of rooms, each of which has a list of items.

To be clear: If a house has no rooms with a red item in it, i don't want the house to be in the JSON object at all. If it only has some rooms with red items in it, i only want those rooms in the object. And finally of course, for the rooms with red items in it, i only want those red items to be in the object.

How can i best do this using constraints like ->where(), or if not possible, how can i best use raw queries to do it?

EDIT:
I already did create a nested query using whereHas, something along the lines of:

```
House::whereHas('rooms', function ($rooms) {
    $rooms->whereHas('items', function ($items) {
        $items->where('color', 'red);
    });
});
```

While this only gave me houses that had red items in it, it keeps the non-red items of those houses in the object as well.

Comment: `whereHas()` method is your friend at this time. [Official doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Hmm, see my edit. I'm not sure how to extend it to the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To filter out rooms there is not red i believe you can utilize `with()` the optional query.

```
House::with(['rooms.items' => function($query) {
    $query->where('color', 'red');
}])->whereHas('rooms', function ($rooms) {
    $rooms->whereHas('items', function ($items) {
        $items->where('color', 'red);
    });
});
```